# Iterate through JSON object returned as a list with nested dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have very limited experience with JSON, but I have a working function that returns a JSON list with three values, the last value being a nested dictionary. I would like to manipulate the list by singling out the nested dictionary, and then reformatting it.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{'progress': 100,
 'time': 421.0,
 'values': {'sctpFlowsConcurrent': '0',
  'tcpClientEstablishRate': '0',
  'ethRxFrameDataRate': '0',
  'tcpServerEstablished': '12425694',
  'appAttempted': '12373847',
  'tcpServerClosedByReset': '0',
  'ethTxFrameRate': '0',
  'appAttemptedRate': '0',
  'appUnsuccessfulRate': '0',
  'concurrentAppFlows': '2',
  'rxFrames': '99042605',
  'ethTxFrameDataRate': '0',
  'appSuccessfulRate': '0',
  'appIncomplete': '12373847',
  'tcpFlowsConcurrent': '2',
  'ethRxFrames': '99248556',
  'tcpClientClosed': '12373845',
  'tcpClosedByReset': '0',
  'ethRxFrameRate': '0',
  'totalFlowsConcurrent': '2',
  'ethTxFrames': '99249661',
  'txFrames': '99146687',
  'appUnsuccessful': '0',
  'txFrameDataRate': '0',
  'appAborted': '0',
  'tcpServerCloseRate': '0',
  'tcpAttempted': '12477920',
  'tcpAttemptRate': '0',
  'rxFrameDataRate': '0',
  'tcpClientEstablished': '12373847',
  'rxFrameRate': '0',
  'tcpServerEstablishRate': '0',
  'tcpClientCloseRate': '0',
  'txFrameRate': '0',
  'superFlowsConcurrent': '0',
  'tcpClientClosedByReset': '0',
  'tcpServerClosed': '12373840',
  'udpFlowsConcurrent': '0',
  'appSuccessful': '0'}}
```

it is unformatted, which is why I would like to manipulate it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
def send_data():
    bps = BPS(settings.ip, settings.ixia_user, settings.ixia_pass, settings.logger)
    run_id = bps.runTest(modelname='test_name', group=settings.__bps_group)
    send_content = bps.getRealTimeStatistics('run_id')
    for v in send_content:
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            purpose = 'do stuff'
```

The error I get is from `for v in send_content:` stating `E TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

`send_content = bps.getRealTimeStatistics('run_id')` calls a function that returns the previously shown JSON data. I am unsure of how to handle this data type.

```
def getRealTimeStatistics(self, runid, enableRequestPrints=False):
        service = 'https://' + self.ipstr + '/api/v1/bps/tests/operations/getRealTimeStatistics'
        jheaders = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        jdata = json.dumps({'runid': runid})
        r = self.session.post(service, data=jdata, headers=jheaders, verify=False)
        if (enableRequestPrints):
            self.pretty_print_requests(r)
        if (r.status_code == 200):
            return r.json().get('rts')
```

I am a noob with data structures and apologize if this is a simple fix. Thanks so much!

Comment: The JSON data you show is not a list. But the error you are getting suggests `getRealTimeStatistics` is returning `None`.

Comment: If the JSON data is not a list, then is it a dictionary? I know that there is a dictionary within that data, bu is the data itself also a dict?

Comment: This data you showed here is a `python dictionary` with three keys, the third being another dictionary: to get it you just say `data['values']` assuming your data is called `data`

Comment: I tried your method @moctarjallo, but am met with this error ```E       TypeError: string indices must be integers```. However calling that variable without the print statement works fine in the console... but I am confused as to why it does not work in script.

Comment: I have formatted your data, ook at it again and maybe you can see it now. But i don't understand how you are getting that error: it's like you are accessing a `list` whereas here there's only dictionaries..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help! I tried @moctarjallo suggested method with an added step and everything seems to be working fine.

```
def send_ixia_data(bps, run_id, test_name):
    nombre = "Details for " + test_name
    x = bps.getRealTimeStatistics(run_id)
    jsonx = json.loads(x)
    var4 = jsonx['values'] #dict of 'values'
```

So now var4 hold only the nested dictionary in the list. I am unsure of exactly how the `jsonx = json.loads(x)` fixed my issue but things are working properly now. :)